# How to make Ajax post request with Recaptcha in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax, recaptcha

How to post a comment with Recaptcha in `Nodjes` and `Ajax`

the comment is posting without `Ajax` but after adding `Ajax` it started giving me `error`

`POST http://localhost:3000/events/60ae6778f7b60c30a51f5b65/createcomment 400 (Bad Request)`

I don't know what I am doing wrong because the Recaptcha token is coming through in Ajax.

I need help. I don't know how else to make it work.

```
 $('#post-comment').on('click', function (event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/events/<%= event._id %>/createcomment",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      name: $('#username').val(),
      description: $('#descriptioncomment').val(),
      captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse(),
    },

  });
});
```

my form

```
<div class="container" id="comment-form">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-push-2 col-sm-12">

  <form action="/events/<%= event._id %>/createcomment" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="name" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea name="description" id="descriptioncomment" class="form-control" placeholder="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6fdafdfadfdfdfdfdfdfadffddkUvX_oyJ"></div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" id="post-comment" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    </div>
     
  </form>
  <ul id="commentList" class="list-group">
  </ul>
</div>
```

my post route

```
router.post("/:eventId/createcomment", async (req, res) => {
  const event = await Event.findOne({ _id: req.params.eventId });
  if (!req.body["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "reCaptcha token is missing" });
  }

  try {
    const googleVerifyUrl = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}
&response=${req.body["g-recaptcha-response"]}`;

    // console.log(googleVerifyUrl);

    const response = await axios.post(googleVerifyUrl);

    const { success } = response.data;

    if (success) {
        const event_comment = new Eventcomment();
        event_comment.description = req.body.description;
        event_comment.name = req.body.name;
        event_comment.event = event._id;
        if (req.body.description && req.body.name) {
            await event_comment.save();

            event.eventcomments.push(event_comment._id);
            await event.save();
            let comments = event.eventcomments;
            res.json({ comments: comments });
        }
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid Captcha. Try again." });
    }
} catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "reCaptcha error." });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of searching i have managed to figure out the problem and fixed it.

i changed the recaptcha in ajax to this  `"g-recaptcha-response": grecaptcha.getResponse()` instead of this   `captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse(),` that I was having before.